# How to ship values from text file to convert this text file to python list with less values?

Tags: python, text, arduino, readline

I'm studying the difference of temperature between cities and forests.
I used 6 temperatures sensors from arduino and I let the program run for about 12h. Arduino should give me values each second (I forgot to edit it..).
I made 2 python program:
The first one who put arduino values into a text file.
The second one who convert my text file to a python list and who made lists for each sensors.
The problem is that now I want to make a graph showing the temperature change over time with the lists I made but I have to much values in (about 23337 values per lists) so I want to tell to python to skip values but I don't know how to do it.
(I'm French so I apologies if what I wrote is not understandable)

This is how my text file looks like (it has 70011 lines):
~

```
Sensor 1 : 14.56 Sensor 2 : 14.13 Sensor 3 : 14.19 Sensor 4 : 14.13 Sensor 5 : 12.56 Sensor 6 : 14.31 


Sensor 1 : 14.63 Sensor 2 : 14.19 Sensor 3 : 14.19 Sensor 4 : 14.13 Sensor 5 : 12.56 Sensor 6 : 14.31 


Sensor 1 : 14.63 Sensor 2 : 14.19 Sensor 3 : 14.19 Sensor 4 : 14.19 Sensor 5 : 12.63 Sensor 6 : 14.31 


Sensor 1 : 14.56 Sensor 2 : 14.19 Sensor 3 : 14.19 Sensor 4 : 14.13 Sensor 5 : 12.56 Sensor 6 : 14.31 


Sensor 1 : 14.63 Sensor 2 : 14.13 Sensor 3 : 14.13 Sensor 4 : 14.13 Sensor 5 : 12.56 Sensor 6 : 14.31
```

~
This is my python's code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import serial
import os

X=[]
for i in range(23337):
    X.append(float(i))
        
with open("temperaturevilleforet120523.txt","r") as f:
    A=[]
    B=[]
    C=[]
    D=[]
    E=[]
    F=[]
    for i in range(23337):
        L=f.readline().split(' ')
        print(L)
        A.append(float(L[3]))
        B.append(float(L[7]))
        C.append(float(L[11]))
        D.append(float(L[15]))
        E.append(float(L[19]))
        F.append(float(L[23]))
        f.readline()
        f.readline()
        #want to skip about 300 lines of values

plt.title("évolution de la température en fonction du temps")
plt.xlabel("Temps (s)")
plt.ylabel("Température (°C)")
plt.plot(X,A,label="Capteur ville 3 (°C)")
plt.plot(X,B,label="Capteur forêt 1 (°C)")
plt.plot(X,C,label="Capteur forêt 3 (°C)")
plt.plot(X,D,label="Capteur forêt 2 (°C)")
plt.plot(X,E,label="Capteur ville 2 (°C)")
plt.plot(X,F,label="Capteur ville 1 (°C)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to store a line of values, skip the next 300, then store line and so on? Or what.

Comment: @user19077881 There are 2 blank lines following each observation.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, all you want to do is read 1 line of data and then skip 300 lines approximately, assuming only every third line have data.
so the first thing I would do is just skip empty lines by adding the following lines after the "read" part:

```
for i in range(23337):
    line = f.readline()
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue

    # the rest of the code goes here
    L = line.split(' ')
    print(L)
```

Now you want to read one line and skip 99, right, so add a counter for the lines read:

```
counter = -1
for i in range(23337):
    line = f.readline()
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue

    counter += 1 # counts the number of non-empty lines 
    if counter % 100 != 0: # will be true in 0, 100, 200 and so on
        continue

    # the rest of the code goes here
    L = line.split(' ')
    print(L)
```

basically, I would rather do an average of the values instead of sampling 1/100 of them, but that's a good start

Comment: The OP says **about** 23337 so it might be better to use `for line in f` instead of `for i ... readline()`

Comment: @user19077881 - definitely, there are many things I would change in his code, but since he is clearly new to this, I believe its better to give incremental changes rather than a complete re-write.